# Which version of NEST NuGet package should be used with Elasticsearch 1.x?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We are upgrading Elasticsearch to version 1.1 (from 0.20), and some of the tests fail. We also upgraded NEST Elasticsearch library to the latest stable version (0.12.0). The failure is related to "custom_filters_score" elements being deprecated in ES 0.90 and replaced with "function_score", but NEST 0.12.0 seems to generate JSON with "custom_filter_score", and this is no longer accepted by ES 1.1.

So the question is whether there is a stable NEST release that supports ES 1.x function scores or we will have to upgrade to NEST 1.0 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NEST 1.0 beta 1` is the latest prerelease version hosted on nuget.org

We host continuous builds on https://www.myget.org/gallery/elasticsearch-net that gets published based on every commit to the `develop` branch that passes all the unit tests.

We are very very close (mid july) to delivering a stable NEST 1.0 version to nuget.org that works against any 1.0+ version of elasticsearch:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/pull/751

If at all possible I would move to the continuous builds, a lot of significant changes have been pushed since the `NEST 1.0 beta 1` release.

The documentation for the breaking changes is moving from `NEST 0.12` to the `1.0 beta 1` release. Part of our final release schedule will be to fully document going from `NEST 0.12` to `NEST 1.0`

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/breaking-changes.html

Another great resource to take into consideration is elasticsearch's own breaking changes page:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking-changes.html